# How to pre-select data to mat-selection-list from array

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am getting string like this, 55,118,122,126,116,58,125,119,132 from API.
These are the ids. I have a angular mat-selection-list. I want to initially select these value. So, basically i want to update existing data and send it to again.

this is my Mat selection list.

```
 <mat-selection-list #yuvakslist  [(ngModel)]="preselectedOptions" 
(selectionChange)="onChangeYuvak()">
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let yuvak of yuvaks" class="mt-1" [value]="yuvak.user_id">
          <nb-user name="{{yuvak.cnt_first_name + ' ' + 
 yuvak.cnt_last_name}}" size="large" title="{{yuvak.cnt_mobile_no}}"
          picture="{{thumbnailImg}}{{yuvak.profile_picture}}">
          </nb-user>
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
```

i tried assigning all the ids i receive from API to array like this.

```
const preselectedOptions: Number[] = data.data.present_contact;
```

i want to pre-select those values onto mat-selection-list. So, i can update form.

Comment: preselectedOptions: Number[] is an array but preselectedoptions need to be single element.

Comment: @tanmay, your preselectedOptions must be a variable of your .ts, therefore this variable must be an array, so if you get a string use **split** to create the array: preselectedOptions =yourdata.split(','). I made an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcxfbe?file=app/list-selection-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ngModel` its better to use [angular reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) to accomplish this.

Here is an example

**`app.component.html`**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Users" [formControl]="userForm" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of userList" [value]="user">
            {{user.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    userList: any[] = [
        { name: 'Robin', id: 1 }, 
        { name: 'Pandey', id: 2 }
    ];
    userForm: FormControl;

    constructor() {
        this.userForm = new FormControl([this.userList[0]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using mat-selection-list not mat-select